# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of nonsymmetric complex tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, eigenvector, tridiagonal-matrices

I wonder if it is possible to find analytically all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the following $2n \times 2n$ non-symmetric complex tridiagonal matrix

$$M = i \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & a & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
  b & 0 & c & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
  0 & -c & 0 & a &\cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots& \vdots \\\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots& \vdots \\\
  \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots& \vdots \\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -c & 0 & a \\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & b & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$$

where $a, b, c \in \mathbb R$, and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

I have read many of the posts dealing with problems that share common features, but are not exactly the same.

Comment: You may as well divide the whole matrix by $i$...

Comment: If $c = 0$, then $\rm M$ is block diagonal $$\mathrm M = i \mathrm I_n \otimes \begin{bmatrix} 0 & a\\ b & 0\end{bmatrix}$$ whose eigenvalues are $\pm i \sqrt{ab}$, each with multiplicity $n$.

Comment: Doesn't look very pleasing in 4x4 case http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B0,+a,+0,0%5D,+%5Bb,0,c,0%5D,%5B0,-c,0,a%5D,+%5B0,0,b,0%5D%5D and it fails to compute the eigenvalues for 6x6 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B0,+a,+0,0,+0,+0%5D,+%5Bb,0,c,0,0,0%5D,%5B0,-c,0,a,0,0%5D,+%5B0,0,b,0,c,0%5D,+%5B0,0,0,-c,0,a%5D,+%5B0,0,0,0,b,0%5D%5D

Comment: @Rodrigo. In general $c\neq0$